# Why is variance of a non-random variable zero?

Tags: variance

In deriving ${Var}(\hat{\beta_1})$ in simple linear regression model, I came across following derivation. Why are the variances of non-random terms zero below?

\begin{align}
\text{Var}(\hat{\beta_1})
& = \text{Var} \left(\frac{\sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y})}{\sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})^2} \right) \\
&= \text{Var} \left(\frac{\sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})(\beta_0 + \beta_1x_i + u_i )}{\sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})^2} \right)\;\;\; \\
&= \text{Var} \left(\frac{\sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})u_i}{\sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})^2} \right), \;\;\;\text{noting only $u_i$ is a random variable} \\
\end{align}

Comment: Where did you get the second equation?

Comment: Because they are never different from their mean.

Comment: You don't actually need a definition or concept of variance of "non-random terms".  This calculation merely uses the fact that $\operatorname{Var}(X)=\operatorname{Var}(X+c)$ for any random variable $X$ and constant $c$. That fact is readily derived from any of the usual definitions of variance. It is also intuitively obvious: since the variance is supposed to be a measure of the *spread* of a random variable, and *shifting* random variables (by adding a constant to them) doesn't change their spread, the variance shouldn't change.

Answer (score 2):

In qualitative terms, non-random variables have a single value that does not vary, and thus have zero variance.

If it helps, you can think of scalar variables as having a distribution with a single infinitely sharp peek. This type of distribution can be represented in equations with a [delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). One way to derive the delta function is as the [limit of the PDF of a Normal Distribution as its standard deviation goes to zero](http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/221a/delta.pdf):

$\delta(t) = \lim_{\sigma\to0} \frac{e^{-t^2/2 \sigma^2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma}$.

Since $\text{Var} = \sigma^2$, variance also goes to zero as standard deviation goes to zero. Thus, in this view non-random variables are the same as random variables, but with zero variance.